# identify select drop-down text using jquery $(this)

Tags: jquery, select, text, this, drop-down-menu

I've got several select elements on a page e.g.

```
<select class="dd" id="dropdown1">
    <option value="123">Option A</option>
    <option value="234">Option B</option>
</select>
<select class="dd" id="dropdown2">
    <option value="456">Option C</option>
</select>
```

etc etc

I would like to use jquery's $(this) to identify which of the several drop-downs have been selected and return their textual value.

I can use something like:

```
$("#dropdown1 :selected").text()
```

To return a specified entry but when I try to add $(this) into the mix it doesn't work.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using the same class for them all, you can use that:

```
$(".dd").change(function(){
  alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
});
```

To get the `value` option of the selected value, you can use the `val()` method instead.

Note that you can also use the `starts with ^` selector like this:

```
$("select[id^='dropdown']").change(function(){
  alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
});
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: $('option:selected', $(this)).text() worked great for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function which will give you the currently selected item value in the drop down list:

```
var selectedValue = $('#dropdown1').val();
```

And to get the text and not the value:

```
var selectedText = $('#dropdown1 option:selected').text();
```

`$(this)` is more commonly used in the context of an event handler like [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/), etc...

Comment: the issue here is that #dropdown2 doesn't get detected, in the real code I don't want to have to identify each of the dropdowns one-by-one